# Getting text from one of the columns from a grid

Tags: protractor, automated-tests, ui-automation

I have a grid table having many columns and I have to get the text of values of 1st column. The grid table structure is shown below

There is a class for a complete row and then inside this class and each column cell has the same class

```
    <div row-index= 'row1'>
       <div col-id= 'datecolumn2' /div>
       <div col-id= Name1 /div>
       <div col-id= city1 /div>
    /div>

    <div row-index= 'row2'>
       <div col-id= datecolumn2 /div>
       <div col-id= Name2 /div>
       <div col-id= city2 /div>
    /div>
```

like this, there are around 1000 rows. I have to traverse through each row and get the text of only date column values

Expected: I should get the text of date column class in an array

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to iterate through each row and get the value for datecolumn. From your code I see the class name for row and column are shown as they are not same classname. But I assume they are same. It would be more helpfull if you can copy the code from your source. Anyhow with minimal information, I have following code that works to read though the dateColumn from each row and outputs the data in that column.

```
const datecolumns = element.all(by.css("div.row .datecolumn"));
 //If there is another child tag below datecolumn and the text is in that tag then you need to include that class in the above element finder 

            datecolumns.map(function (eachDateColumn, index) {
                eachDateColumn.getText().then(function (dateValue) {
                    console.log("Date value in column " + index + " is " + dateValue)
                })
            })
```

More straight way:

```
const datecolumns = element.all(by.css("div.row .datecolumn")).getText();
```

Comment: I have updated my code and it doesn't have class now. It has col-id tag for every column cell. can I still use the same way  you told or do I need to some modification in locator as there is col-id, not class

Answer (score 0):

It is exactly 1000 rows? do they start at `<div class = 'row1'>` and end in `<div class = 'row1000'>`?
If that's the case, the element locator itself should be:
`element(by.css('.row1 .datecolumn2'));`
Then if you're looping through all the rows, just change it like this:

```
for (i= 1; i < rows.length; i++) {
    element(by.css('.row' + i + '.datecolumn2')).getText();
    // here you do whatever you need to do with the text
}
```

Comment: I have updated my code and it doesn't have class now. It has col-id tag for every column cell. can I still use the same way you told or do I need to some modification in locator as there is col-id, not class

Comment: If the row class is same for every row in the table then yes you can replace the column class with Id. Just use the below code const datecolumns = element.all(by.css("div.row #datecolumn"));